# I always fail to run with an error description in the flutter contact picker

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

This problem only exists when I run it on Android, for iOS there is no problem, I run it smoothly.
This is an error display when I try to run it :

e: /Users/yohanescatur/Documents/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttercontactpicker-4.2.1/android/src/main/kotlin/me/schlaubi/fluttercontactpicker/ContactPicker.kt: (52, 280): Unresolved reference: stackTraceToString

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':fluttercontactpicker:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 28s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

can you help me find this problem?

Comment: I've been running into the same exact problem. Any luck so far?

Comment: This looks like you use an earlier version of Kotlin than 1.4 can you please check your gradle version and set kotlin to 1.4.21?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set kotlin to 1.4.21

this is what i did to solve this problem.

Comment: didin't work for me

Comment: Set kotlin to the last version.

Answer (score 0):

set kotlin to 1.5.10

this is what i did to solve this problem.

please flutter clean and pub get after upgrade kotlin version